# What is the accepted C++ template definition for pointer-only types?

Tags: c++, templates

I want a type that simply wraps a pointer stored as a member.

```
struct Foo { };

template <typename T>
struct MyHandle final
{
    MyHandle(T* data) : m_Ptr(data) { };

    T* m_Ptr;
};

void main()
{
    MyHandle<Foo> fooHandle(new Foo());
}
```

This is sufficient since I restrict the constructor to only take a pointer of `T`. However, I've heard from people get confused by this because they're used to seeing something like `MyHandle<Foo*>` instead since they explicitly understand that it's a pointer inside.

So I have two options to accommodate this:

1: static assert on type - my gripe with this is that the `MyHandle` definition is now strange. It looks like it has a reference member, but it's actually a pointer...

```
struct Foo { };

template <typename T>
struct MyHandle final
{
    static_assert(std::is_pointer<T>::value, "T must be a pointer.");

    MyHandle(T data) : m_Ptr(data) { };

    T m_Ptr; // Looks like a reference, is actually a pointer since T is like a find + replace on the template declaration in main()
};

void main()
{
    MyHandle<Foo> fooHandle(new Foo()); // ERROR AT COMPILE! Good!
    MyHandle<Foo*> fooHandle2(new Foo());
}
```

2: forward declared specialization - this seems like a decent compromise, but if you use the undefined `MyHandle` you only get an ambiguous error. I couldn't find a static_assert that works well.

```
struct Foo { void Test() { } };

template <typename T> struct MyHandle; // Can you leverage static assert here somehow?

template <typename T>
struct MyHandle<T*> final
{
    MyHandle(T* data) : m_Ptr(data) { };

    T* m_Ptr;
};

void main()
{
    MyHandle<Foo> fooHandle(new Foo()); // ERROR WONT COMPILE! Good!
    MyHandle<Foo*> fooHandle2(new Foo());
    fooHandle2.m_Ptr->Test(); // all good, no double ptrs
}
```

I'm leaning toward the second solution since the class definition pleases me, but perhaps the pointer assert is the more "accepted" solution? Or, I could tell people to just use the original and ignore their complaints as well.

Comment: Follow the practice of the pointer-like types in the standard library, specifically `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.  `unique_ptr<int>` isn't the same as `unique_ptr<int*>`.

Comment: Yes, that is why I'm asking. :) I wouldn't have entertained the complaint otherwise.

Comment: *"people get confused ... used to seeing something like `MyHandle<Foo*>`"* I say this is nonsense.

Comment: I have to agree with the other posters. Anyone who gets confused when `MyHandle<Foo>` contains a pointer is *not* a native C++ coder. Just let `MyHandle<T>` contain a `T*` and ignore the complaints.

Comment: Would they get less confused by a different name like `handle_ptr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::remove_pointer`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {
  void Test() { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
};

template <typename PTR>
struct MyHandle final {
  static_assert(std::is_pointer<PTR>::value);
  using T = typename std::remove_pointer<PTR>::type;
  MyHandle(T* ptr) : m_Ptr(ptr) {}
  T* m_Ptr;
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  MyHandle<Foo*> fooHandle2(&foo);
  fooHandle2.m_Ptr->Test();
  return 0;
}
```

Opinion: I tend to agree with Stephen Newell's comment. If you name your class `MyPtr` instead, then declaring `MyPtr<int>` would be following a similar pattern to `std::unique_ptr<int>`.

Comment: interesting solution! I've never seen remove_pointer before

Comment: Such a template parameter can be misused by specifying it manually. I'd rather use `using T = std::remove_pointer_t<PTR>;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Agreed; answer updated. Thanks!